# WP-All Import add_post hook with original data

Tags: php, wordpress, wpallimport

I use WP-All Import with the WooCommerce add-on to import products in WooCommerce. In the original xml I have 3 discount categories for different user roles. With the plugin Customer Specific Pricing for WooCommerce (https://wisdmlabs.com/woocommerce-user-specific-pricing-extension/) I'm able to show different prices for those roles.

This plugin saves his data to a separate table (`wp_wusp_role_pricing_mapping`), which mean that WP-All Import cannot insert the data directly.

But, WP All Import has a hook `pmxi_saved_post` which is called every time when a post is saved or updated. (http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/action-reference/)

In that function I must be able to insert the records to the wusp_role_price_mapping table, because I need the post_id, but, and that is my question: I need also the original data from the XML where the separate discount rules are in available. Can I access that data in the hook action?

For your information this is how the data looks in the xml, and how it must be saved in the database.

```
<Korting>
    <KortingCategorie>EH Markt 71 %</KortingCategorie>
    <Percentage>40</Percentage>
    <Prijs>0,0000</Prijs>

    <KortingCategorie>EH winkel 35%</KortingCategorie>
    <Percentage>40</Percentage>
    <Prijs>0,0000</Prijs>

    <KortingCategorie>EH Winkel 45%</KortingCategorie>
    <Percentage>40</Percentage>
    <Prijs>0,0000</Prijs>

    <KortingCategorie>EH Winkel 50%</KortingCategorie>
    <Percentage>40</Percentage>
    <Prijs>0,0000</Prijs>
</Korting>
```

As you can see, the name of the discountcategory/userrole (`KortingCategorie` in the xml) does not always contain the right discount percentage, and the discount is different per product.

```
+----+--------------+---------+---------+------------------------+------------+
| id |     role     |  price  | min_qty | flat_or_discount_price | product_id |
+----+--------------+---------+---------+------------------------+------------+
|  1 | eh_winkel_50 | 40.0000 |       1 |                      2 |       5445 |
|  2 | eh_winkel_45 | 40.0000 |       1 |                      2 |       5445 |
|  3 | eh_markt     | 40.0000 |       1 |                      2 |       5445 |
+----+--------------+---------+---------+------------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found another solution:

With importing, I add the discount groups to the custom fields, and with the hook and the `get_post_meta` and and `wpdb->insert()` functions I add the right values at the right place.